# calculating miles by using (x,y) in object orientation python

Tags: python, function, class, object, orientation

Hello I'm brand new to object orientation and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. The problem is with the amount of money the Taxi object has, everything else is apparently working correctly.

This is my current code:

```
class Car()
def __init__( self , mpg=15 , capacity=20 , money=25 ):
#set tank capacity to max and miles is 0
    self.mpg = mpg
    self.fuel = capacity
    self.money = money
    self.capacity = capacity 
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.curr_x = 0
    self.curr_y = 0
    self.passenger = False

def driveTo( self , x , y ):
    miles = math.sqrt( ( self.x - x )**2 + ( self.y - y )**2 )
    maxdistance = self.mpg * self.fuel 

    if maxdistance < miles:
        return False
    else: 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        self.fuel -= (miles /  self.mpg) 
        return True

class Taxi(Car):

def pickup(self):
    if self.passenger == False:
        self.passenger = True
        self.curr_x = self.x
        self.curr_y = self.y
        return True  
    else:
        False

def dropoff(self):
    if self.passenger == True:
        dist = (self.x - self.curr_x)**2 + (self.y - self.curr_y)**2 )
        if dist == 0:
            self.money += 2
        else:
            self.money += (2+(3*int(dist)))
        self.passenger = False 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The Taxi class returns false for pickup if a passenger is in a car and returns false for drop-off if a passenger is not in the car. After drop off the taxi gets paid at $2 for the pickup plus $3 per mile driven with the passenger. When passenger is picked up, taxi should track the miles it drives while carrying a passenger.

location work by a pair of coordinates --- the y describes how many miles to the north or south a car sits from its origin and the x describes how many miles to the east or west.

I can't wrap my head around how to fix this so any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if anything is unclear since I am new to this site :)

Comment: You should look into https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we don't have to read through all of your code to find what we need to fix. Also, provide some examples of input.

Comment: Don't forget to get the indentation right; functions that belong to a class should have 1 indentation level greater than the class itself.

Comment: I don't know what exactly your problem is, maybe you should be more specific. One thing I see though is with the line `self.money += (2+(3*int(dist)))` would not get you any cents, unless you don't want to calculate cents. But that wouldn't be very realistic. If you went with floating point values you wouldn't have to do any casting either.

Comment: How do you update `self.x` and `self.y`. Do you have a `drive`method in the `Car` class?

Comment: @JohanL yes! i've added it to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a mathematical one. When calculating the distance in your `dropoff` method you simply forget the square root operation. Change

```
dist = (self.x - self.curr_x)**2 + (self.y - self.curr_y)**2
```

to

```
dist = math.sqrt((self.x - self.curr_x)**2 + (self.y - self.curr_y)**2)
```

in `dropoff` and the money will look more sane.